# (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? BaseSlidingController)?.openMenu() return nil Swift 4.2

Tags: swift

I have a problem with the above stated. I can not find the exact information on the forums. Most of them are outdated and I have written the code programmatically.  I have a controller that contains a view to edit the profile. I can not access that after changing the function listed below. I have a rootviewcontroller set to something else, but I tried the UiApplication calls anyway and it return nil and I can not open the profile controller. This is the function listed below.

```
@objc func handleOpen2() {
    (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? BaseSlidingController)?.openMenu()
}
```

Xcode does not give me an error but I can not get my menu to open. My rootviewcontroller is set to something else in app delegate. I have a controller that is used to control the sliding menu when I press the edit profile button.

```
    func openMenu() {
        isMenuOpened = true
        redViewLeadingConstraint.constant = menuWidth
        redViewTrailingConstraint.constant = menuWidth
        performAnimations()
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
```

This code is used to open my side bar menu with the information I need and also to perform animations as well. I was wondering if someone had any idea what I can do different instead in my handleOpen2 function. If you need more code, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Then the root controller is probably something else.

Comment: Do you know how I can make the view show up without messing up anything? If i need the rootviewcontroller to be different, how can I change this function above?

Answer (score 0):

On swift 5 version:

```
(UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController as? BaseSlidingController)?.openMenu()
```